# Can numbers in R be formatted without losing numeric class?

Tags: r, ggplot2, format, plotly

I am making a chart with ggplolty which when mouse is hovered over a bar let you see values of y variable which is in my case big number.

I know that with ggplot you can have separate columns one numeric to get values on chart and the other to format labels. So it's not problem that using format function I get character.

So the question is whether it's possible format number 100000000 as 100 000 000
and it stays numeric so bars can be plotted and plotly labels will show nicely formatted numbers

```
library(ggplot2)
    library(plotly)
    library(scales)

# here you can see numbers on chart after hover not nicely formatted
    df<-data.frame(x=letters[1:6],y=runif(6,120000000,130000000))
    ggplotly(ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_bar(stat="identity"))
# and this unfortunately formats well but converts to character    
    df$y<-format(df$y,big.mark = " ")
    class(df$y)
```

Comment: Perhaps you need `scale_y_continuous(labels = ...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the hover text:

```
tmp <- ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
p <- plotly_build(tmp)
p$data[[1]]$text <-prettyNum(df$y, big.mark = " ")
p
```